# No Eulerian walk in a graph, and how to fix it

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

> Explain why a simple graph $G=(V,E)$ has no Eulerian walk, where the vertices are $V =\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ and the edges are $E=\{ab,ae,af,be,cd,ce,cf,df\}$.
>
> Show that it is possible to add one edge to $G$ to obtain a simple graph still, that does have an Eulerian walk, and find such a walk. There may be more than one way to do this; identify all ways to add the edge.

When working out this question, I found out that vertices $a,c,e$ and $f$ have odd degrees of 3. But a graph cannot have more than 2 vertices of odd degree to have a Eulerian path, so $G$ doesn't have an Eulerian path.

That is all that I have come up with and I am not sure how to approach the second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When approaching graph theory problems dealing with a specific graph, drawing always helps:

[image: The graph]

Since you have already shown that no Eulerian walk exists in the graph, I will concentrate on how to add an edge to this graph so that it *does* have an Eulerian walk.

Adding one edge to the graph flips the parities of the vertices it connects – odd to even, even to odd. We have four odd vertices and we need two, so we should add an edge between two vertices of odd degree; those vertices are $a,c,e,f$ and have a black spot in my drawing, so we would have six edges to choose from. However, to keep the graph *simple* we cannot add an edge between two vertices that are already connected by an edge; this whittles down the possible edges to $ac$ and $ef$.

Here are possible Eulerian paths for both augmented graphs.
[image] $+ac:$ `fcdfaceabe`
[image] $+ef:$ `afeabecdfc`

Comment: Thank you so much that makes so much sense. I was making the question more complicated in my head. :)

Comment: @user376279 Note that you can mark my answer as accepted (to show that you found it useful; you're new so I thought it would be good to explain this). There's a tick beside my answer you can click.